# What is the event viewer and why do scammers send you to it?

Tags: event-viewer

I recently received a scam call in which they tried* to direct me to the event viewer, but I couldn't seem to find any reason that they would try to gain access to it. It does not appear to have any special privileges.

- What is it?
- Why do scammers send you to it?

*We all like to have fun with these.

Comment: So they can show you all the supposed "errors" and "warnings" and then get you to allow remote access so they can fix it. If you agree they will install a trojan and/or scam your credit card.

Comment: The event viewer is where windows exposes its logs to the end user. Its big and scary, and the average, non computer savvy user has no idea what most of it is. 
As such, many of these scammers will point you at an innocuous event viewer entry, claim that its something horribad, and try to talk you into giving remote access.  T

Comment: Why, because the are Scamming you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Event Viewer can be used to view Windows logs, which will be filled with entries related to Windows normal functioning.

These logs will include numerous warnings and errors which may seem alarming, but are totally benign and a regular part of even a new Windows installation.

Using these harmless alerts, a scammer can frighten someone who is unfamiliar with those logs into thinking they have a very serious problem with their system requiring expert assistance to resolve.

The scammer will then offer to provide help, so long as the hapless mark will provide a credit card number.

I've excerpted below a portion of an interaction between an Ars Technica writer and a scammer, which the writer describes at 
[“I am calling you from Windows”: A tech support scammer dials Ars Technica](http://arstechnica.com/tech-policy/2012/10/i-am-calling-you-from-windows-a-tech-support-scammer-dials-ars-technica/):

> I wanted to know just what it felt like to be on the receiving end of
> such a call. I wanted to know how a group of scammers half a world
> away convinced random and often tech-illiterate people to do things
> like run the built-in Windows Event Viewer, then connect to a website,
> download software, and install it (together, no easy feat for many
> mainstream users).

> I wanted to know just how the scammers eventually
> convinced their marks to open up remote control of their PCs to
> strangers who had just called them on the telephone. ... I knew
> already a key part of the scam involved showing people innocent error
> messages in the Windows Event Viewer, then trying to convince them
> these were caused by a virus...

> "Yeah. Sir, these are the viruses in your computer. They may harm your computer at any point of
> time. And these viruses are corrupting your data and using your
> personal information like that. So do one thing: can you try to delete
> any error, any warning?" ... "Yeah, sir, these are un-deletable
> viruses."